# C#- http client response help request

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static async Task checkIMEI( double IMEI)
    {
        
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://kelpom-imei-checker1.p.rapidapi.com/api?service=model&imei=" + IMEI.ToString() ),
            Headers =
                {
                    { "X-RapidAPI-Host", "kelpom-imei-checker1.p.rapidapi.com" },
                    { "X-RapidAPI-Key", "key" },
                 }
        };
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            object result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                         

                                             
            MessageBox.Show("\n" + result);
            
        }
    }
```

Running this code I get the following
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRgJL.png)

I would like to further break up this response and the individual data and assign it to a variable such as

string ModelNum= model_nb >> should show "SM-G891A"

String Brand = brand >> should show "Samsung Korea"

Your help would be appriciated.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the JSON Parser classes

Comment: also an IMEI isn't a floating point number

Answer (score 2):

first your Client is bad practice use this link [HttpClientFactory Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to refactor your client.

Then Create Class for your needed model for ex:

```
public class Mobile
{
    public string ModelNum { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
 }
```

then you should deserialize your result to your model:

```
 var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Mobile>(result);
```